# populating a zend form helper with data

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I have a custom view helper that I am using to add elements to a form. I am trying to get it to properly populate data that has been saved to the database.

The problem is that that data is not getting passed into the view helper

```
class View_Helper_JQMy extends ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper_UiWidget
{

    public function jqMy($id, $value=null, $attribs=null, $options=null)
    {}
```

When I am building the form in the form controller and setting all the options there, they get properly passed in and the form builds.

However when I call $form->populate($data) from the controller, this form element does not get data

My best guess is that the jqMy helper is being called before $value is being set with the data I want to populate in the form. But I can't identify how this differs from the core zend form elements populating.

Answer (score 1):

You can access to the view Object into the view helper using the propertie $this->view from the helpers. The abstract 
Zend_View_Helper_Abstract have the property view. You maybe use something like $this->view->form->getValues() or something like that

Comment: im not sure I understand where your going with that. The problem is the form is not getting the values from populate earlier in the process I think.